# GaussianProcessRegressor with geometric anisotropy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is it possible to define a kernel for the `GaussianProcessRegressor` which uses "geometric anisotropy"?

I know it's possible to define anisotropy with some of the existing kernels, but it seems to only allow anisotropy parallel to the dimensions. Consider the case of related dimensions (for example a spatial x/y coordinate), I want the anisotropy to be able to take into account an angle by which to rotate the "ellipse" defined by the two length scales (those would become the major and minor axis).

It's not obvious to me whether this is already possible with the current kernels in Scikit-Learn, or if I should create my own kernel by subclassing one of the existing.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern, ConstantKernel

# training data
ygrid, xgrid = np.mgrid[-2:3:1, -2:3:1]
X_train = np.stack([ygrid.flat, xgrid.flat], axis=1)
y_train = np.eye(*ygrid.shape).ravel()

# define the kernel
c = ConstantKernel(constant_value=y_train.mean(), constant_value_bounds='fixed')
m = Matern(length_scale=[0.5, 0.5], nu=0.5)

kernel = c * m

# fit
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After fitting the kernel parameters are:

```
print(gp.kernel_.get_params())
{'k1': 0.447**2,
 'k2': Matern(length_scale=[0.444, 0.444], nu=0.5),
 'k1__constant_value': 0.2,
 'k1__constant_value_bounds': 'fixed',
 'k2__length_scale': array([0.4443361, 0.4443361]),
 'k2__length_scale_bounds': (1e-05, 100000.0),
 'k2__nu': 0.5}
```

A detailed prediction:

```
ygrid, xgrid = np.mgrid[-3:4:0.05, -3:4:0.05]
X_predict = np.stack([ygrid.flat, xgrid.flat], axis=1)

y_predict = gp.predict(X_predict)
y_predict = y_predict.reshape(xgrid.shape)
```

The left axes shows the training data (25 samples), and the right one the prediction on a finer grid:

[image: gp_example]

It's already obvious from the fit that the anisotropy doesn't add anything in this case since the data correlates along the diagonal and the anisotropy from the `Matern` kernel doesn't capture that. The image shows that the prediction could be a lot more smooth along the diagonal if I'm able to specify this somewhere.

For my use-case, the angle can be anything (0-360 degrees), and I don't know it beforehand, so I can't transform the input coordinates.

Is there are workaround for this with the existing kernels? Or how can I add this behavior by creating a new kernel (preferably Matern-based)?

Comment: Usually multi-dimensional kernel are tensorized. I am not sure about sklearn implementation but if it is the same, you will not be able to achieve what you want. You should consider rotating first your data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, subclassing one of the existing kernels and defining your own kernel function is your best bet.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Kernel

class GeometricAnisotropicKernel(Kernel):
    def __init__(self, length_scale, angle, nu=0.5):
        self.length_scale = length_scale
        self.angle = angle
        self.nu = nu
        
    def __call__(self, X, Y=None, eval_gradient=False):
        # Convert the angle to radians
        angle_rad = np.deg2rad(self.angle)
        
        # Rotate the coordinates by the angle
        X_rot = np.dot(X, [[np.cos(angle_rad), -np.sin(angle_rad)],
                           [np.sin(angle_rad), np.cos(angle_rad)]])
        if Y is not None:
            Y_rot = np.dot(Y, [[np.cos(angle_rad), -np.sin(angle_rad)],
                               [np.sin(angle_rad), np.cos(angle_rad)]])
        
        # Compute the kernel function using the rotated coordinates
        k = Matern(length_scale=self.length_scale, nu=self.nu)(X_rot, Y_rot, eval_gradient)
        
        return k
```

You can then use this custom kernel in the GaussianProcessRegressor as follows:

```
# training data
ygrid, xgrid = np.mgrid[-2:3:1, -2:3:1]
X_train = np.stack([ygrid.flat, xgrid.flat], axis=1)
y_train = np.eye(*ygrid.shape).ravel()

# define the kernel
c = ConstantKernel(constant_value=y_train.mean(), constant_value_bounds='fixed')
m = GeometricAnisotropicKernel(length_scale=[0.5, 0.5], angle=45)

kernel = c * m

# fit
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't really address the issue because it requires the angle to be known, and apply preprocessing on the coordinates. It would make it a nested optimization, as apart from integrating directly in the kernel. I've again looked at it a little more and I suspect the main requirement would be to define it has a `Hyperparameter` which requires calculating the gradient and returning it as part of `k` as well.